# SqlBulkCopy creating more rows than in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to import around 66k rows from a CSV. The CSV is imported into a DataTable and then passed into the following method below.

It seems to replicate the same rows (or reset once it reaches the end) indefinitely into the database. Debug ran for around 30mins and created close to 350k records duplicating each row in the DataTable around 5 times.

I can confirm that the amount of rows in the DataTable is correct so I must be missing something, any ideas?

Note: I added the s.BatchSize with the hopes that it will only import that amount which is not the case.

```
  /*
     * StoreImportedData()
     * This method will store all of the imported data from the datatable to the SQL server database.
     * 
     *  
     */

    private Boolean StoreImportedData(DataTable csvFileData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
                {
                    s.DestinationTableName = "Staging";
                    // Amount of rows to issue in the batch: (currently value is around 60k)
                    s.BatchSize = csvFileData.Rows.Count;
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("remark", "ReportDate");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("ipAddress", "IPAddress");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("hostName", "HostName");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("macAddress", "MacAddress");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("deviceName", "PrinterName");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("comment", "CenterCode");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("userName", "CustomerCode");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("userDisplayName", "CustomerName");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("printerBlackTotal", "TPrintBw");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("printerColorTotal", "TPrintCol");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("copyBlackTotal", "TCopyBw");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("copyColorTotal", "TCopyCol");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("scanTotal", "TScan");
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add("faxBlackTotal", "TFaxBw");
                    s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error has occured with the import SQL operation: " + e.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a unique index or primary key on the Staging table?

Comment: Yes there is a primary key (Id) which auto increments

Comment: My guess would be to add a unique index onto the table to prevent multiple insertions, the primary key being an auto increment wouldn't help that.

Comment: BatchSize affects how many rows are inserted at a time, it shouldn't have anything to affect on the duplication you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s.WriteToServer(csvFileData.CreateDataReader());
```

Comment: got an Exception: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: That means you have more columns than those mentioned above.

Comment: That's correct, I figured the mapping would ignore the remainder of the rows. Is there a way for me to set it to only work with the rows set in the mapping?

Comment: You can remove the unwanted column from the datatable using `DataTable.Columns.Remove()` method. Eg; `csvFileData.Columns.Remove("Col1");`